ESC/POS print nv image using ASCII commando
I'm using an Epson printer which supports ESC/POS. We send data in ASCII
Now we would like to add an image to each print. We were able to upload the image to the printer and save it. It's location is 32, 32
I found out that by using the FS p commando we should be able to tell the printer to print the image we have uploaded however I have no idea how the complete string should look like.
Any ideas?
We haven't tried anything as we have no idea what values to use...

You can see the specifications here, so check it out. ESC/POS® Command Reference for TM Printers
